# Client-side JavaScript without is:inline directive on Astro

Tags: astrojs

According to the [Scripts and Event Handling](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/#using-script-in-astro) documentation in Astro, it looks like adding a `script` tag to an astro component should add the corresponding javascript, bundled and inserted in the `head` of the resulting build (static).

I can confirm this behaviour on one of my components:

This is the source for my Header component, which contains a `script` tag
[image]

which then as per the documentation, gets bundled and inserted in the `head` of the static webpage:
[image]

However, this is not the case for another component.

`ImagePreview.astro`

```
---
import { Image } from "astro:assets";

export interface Props {
  src: string;
  alt: string;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  description: string;
}

const { description, ...props } = Astro.props;
---

<!-- Displayed within the page -->
<figure class="figure-display cursor-pointer">
...
</figure>
<!-- Displayed fullscreen when clicked -->
<div>
...
</div>

<style>
...
</style>

<script>
const displayImage = document.querySelector(".figure-display");
const previewImage = document.querySelector(".figure-preview");

displayImage?.addEventListener("click", () => {
  previewImage?.classList.remove("hidden");
  previewImage?.classList.add("flex");
});
previewImage?.addEventListener("click", () => {
  previewImage.classList.add("hidden");
});
</script>
```

The script at the bottom does not get bundled and added to the website, unless I add `is:inline` directive. What is the difference between these components?

UPDATE:

I looked at it a bit more -- my `ImagePreview.astro` bundles and inserts client side javascript fine in other astro components, but it seems when it is imported and used in an mdx document, it doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of Astro was this with? This was probably cause by this bug — https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/7744 — which was fixed in Astro v2.10.5

Comment: @swithinbank I believe my issue is related to [#5991](https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/5991), where hoisted scripts get missing. I left a comment on the issue, and was prompted to create a [new issue](https://github.com/withastro/astro/issues/8034).

Comment: @swithinbank by the way, the bug still exists with `2.10.5`... which I've reproduced in [this repo](https://github.com/noidwasavailable/astropaper-mdx), so you can just clone and run it